# Weather Layer Above Polygons

Tags: google-maps

Is there anyway to draw a layer, weather, transit, or other so that they appear above polygons?  I'm running into an issue where my polygons are blocking the view of the weather layer.  It would however be very useful to see both at the same time.  Not sure if this is possible but any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: How are you adding the weather layer and the polygons to your map (what does your code look like)?

Comment: **Beware** [from the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/weatherlayer): **Note:** The Weather library - which includes the Weather and Cloud layers - has been deprecated as of June 4, 2014. This library will continue to work until June 4, 2015. After that date, the library will no longer be available.